# Asking for missing semicolon in SQL statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to figure out this error message:

> Missing semicolon at end of SQL statement.

I am using MS Access as database for now, and I have 2 tables: users and import_users_temp_excel. I want to import data from MS Excel to the import_users_temp_excel, and then to merge or copy just new registries into table "users". Basically, I want to avoid duplicates into "users" Table. Here is my code:

```
Dim sqlquery1 As New OleDbCommand
sqlquery1.Connection = con
sqlquery1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
sqlquery1.CommandText = "insert into users ([employeeID], [username], [middlename], [lastname], [level], [ADDR1], [ADDR2], [city], [state], [zip], [warehouse_assig], [timezone], [branchM], [contactinfo], [email], [altemail], [Source]) values(@employeeID, @username, @middlename, @lastname, @level, @ADDR1, @ADDR2, @city, @state, @zip, @warehouse_assig, @timezone, @branchM, @contactinfo, @email, @altemail, @Source)
                         select distinct * from import_users_temp_excel;"
```

But for some reason I got this error "missing semicolon". I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: You didn't put a *semicolon* at the end of your insert statement. Only at the end of the select.

Comment: `INSERT` and `SELECT` are two separate statements. You didn't terminate one of them. Reading the SQL should tell you which one, and the error message tells you exactly what is needed to fix it.

Comment: First, thank you for your time and attention. Yes, that is correct, but now I am getting this error: Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, your `INSERT` and your `SELECT` are two different statements so they both need a semicolon to terminate them.

Try this -

```
        sqlquery1.CommandText = "insert into users ([employeeID], [username], [middlename], [lastname], [level], [ADDR1], [ADDR2], [city], [state], [zip], [warehouse_assig], [timezone], [branchM], [contactinfo], [email], [altemail], [Source]) 
                             values (@employeeID, @username, @middlename, @lastname, @level, @ADDR1, @ADDR2, @city, @state, @zip, @warehouse_assig, @timezone, @branchM, @contactinfo, @email, @altemail, @Source);
                             select distinct * from import_users_temp_excel;"
```

Comment: First, thank you for your time and attention. Yes, that is correct, but now I am getting this error: Characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: Hmm, are you able to run the two statement separately from your application code? First your `INSERT` and then your `SELECT` afterwards in a separate call?

Comment: yes, if I run the code separately. I tried in MS Access.

Comment: Ah don't think I worded that very well - I meant could you run two `OleDbCommand`s from your VB? The `INSERT` first, then the `SELECT`?

Comment: It worked, but the problem is I have a spreadsheet that contains user's data, every week, this spreadsheet is updated, I want to import these data from this spreadsheet to the table import_users_temp_excel, this is a temp table, so after that I transfer the data from this table to table users without duplicates. Here is the full code:

Comment: This is my first time here, I don't know how to organize my code friendly. My apologies.

Comment: No problem :) It might be easier if you add it as an edit to your original post - Others might be able to jump in and help too that way!

Comment: When I execute this code, it gives me the data into import_users_temp_excel, and if I run the code again, it creates duplicates, and nothing is copied to users table.

Comment: OK will have another look!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, as you said, I just created another statement separately... I create at the end before closing the connection a code to execute the statement.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strsql As String = "insert into users SELECT * FROM import_users_temp_excel WHERE  import_users_temp_excel.employeeID Not IN (SELECT employeeID from users)"

Dim command1 As New OleDbCommand
command1 = New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
command1.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
loaddata()
```